# why is the last child not showing up?

Tags: jquery

I have built this fiddle, however the car is not showing up when the textbox val is 50. Why is that?

**http://jsfiddle.net/Z8knE/42/**

```
var interval;
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        var chosenvalue = $(".amount1").val()
        $(".box ul li").hide();
        $(".box ul li:nth-child(" + chosenvalue + ")").show();
}, 100);
```

Comment: Can I ask why you are using an interval?

Comment: Could you not just take that logic and put it into the slider: `slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( ".amount1" ).val( ui.value);
            $(".box ul li").hide();
             $(".box ul li:nth-child(" + ui.value + ")").show();
        }`

Comment: a better approach would be to add the onkeyup event for the textbox and hadle it with the code inside the interval. That way you don't have an eternal javascript that might cause problems. that is if you want to load an image by typing the number in the textbox.

Comment: @ChrisHardie done :) http://jsfiddle.net/Z8knE/41

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are missing image 18, which results in you only having 49 `li` elements / images:

```
<li><img src="http://binekarac.vw.com.tr/images/360/passat/360_passat_00017.png"/></li>
<li><img src="http://binekarac.vw.com.tr/images/360/passat/360_passat_00019.png"/></li>
```

Comment: Nice find, I hadn't even considered looking at the images themselves!

Comment: wow. I have big respect for this. that was HARD to detect. thank you sir !